# How to insert a row into a pandas dataframe in a for loop then decrement the for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, indexing

So I'm trying to for loop through a table and find missing rows and add them in.

```
S-Value
S1
S2
S3
...
S106
S108
S109
```

So S107 is missing.

Currently I'm checking if count = S-value if they equal continue, else add row. However if I add S107 in when count is 107, on the next loop Count is 108 and the table is at S109 so they will continue to be off by one. Coming from C I would decrement the index of the for loop but that doesn't seem to work and just jumps to another part of the table. If I just double increment count I could be possibly missing a row if S108 wasn't there either. Is there a solution to this? or a better way to add a row to the table when its missing, maybe I'm not tackling the problem in a python mindset.

I thought about maybe using a temp variable to store index, is that a bad idea?

```
for ind in RB.index:
    if (flag == 1):
        ind -= 1
        flag = 0
    if (count != int(RB['S-Value'][ind].split('S')[1])):
        print(RB['P-Block'][ind],'.',RB['S-Value'][ind], count)
        RB.loc[ind-0.5] = ['Unmapped','', RB['P-Block'][ind]+'.'+'S'+str(count), RB['P-Block'][ind], 'S'+str(count) ]  # adding a row
        RB = RB.sort_index()
        flag = 1
    print(count)
    count += 1
    if (count == 113):
        count = 1
```

Comment: If i don't increment count the it will still be 107 on the next round and fail 107 != S109

Comment: I suggest you provide a reproducible example. Usually in pandas there are better ways to do things than looping (and some smart pandas person will probably show you!). By reproducible example, I mean adding some sample data that creates a dataframe ... so the code can run start to finish demonstrating the expected or desired behavior with your current code.

Comment: But fwiw, you can decrement your loop in python too (to mimic your c-style, so to speak). Example: https://learnpython.com/blog/decrement-in-python-for-loop/

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you should basically never mutate a data structure while iterating through it. I would advise multiple passes for this. Dead simple way:

- Make a new empty dataframe.
- Iterate through the possible index values. For each index, add a row to the new dataframe. If the index is in your data, add the corresponding row from your dataframe. Otherwise add an empty row.

The new dataframe should be correct.

*note: this is not that performant, but based on the numbers (S-108, etc) you have low hundreds of rows so it should be fine.*

Another approach:

- Loop through once, storing each missing index in another list.
- Then go through the list, adding a row for each index to the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code**

we need [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 to answer your question.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'S-Value': {0: 'S1', 1: 'S2', 2: 'S4', 3: 'S5'},
         'col1': {0: 10, 1: 30, 2: 20, 3: 10}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df:

```
    S-Value col1
0   S1      10
1   S2      30
2   S4      20
3   S5      10
```

---

**Code**

```
num_min, num_max = 1, 5
idx = 'S' + pd.RangeIndex(num_min, num_max + 1, name='S-Value').astype('str')
out = df.set_index('S-Value').reindex(idx).reset_index()
```

out:

```
df:                       out:
  S-Value  col1             S-Value  col1
0      S1  10.0           0      S1  10.0
1      S2  30.0    ->     1      S2  30.0
2      S4  20.0           2      S3   NaN <-- add row
3      S5  10.0           3      S4  20.0
                          4      S5  10.0
```